# php script for executing MySQL statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am trying to perform a INSERT statement to my database. The php file is stored on a server, and I am using $_POST (with swift) to send the content (a score and username) for the statement. However, when I execute the app, nothing happens, but the php-file returns a HTTP-code of 200 (means OK).

So I'm having a hard time determining where the problem resides. Here is the full PHP file, with some stuff censored:

```
<?php
$postVar = $_POST['data'];

$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 

if (!empty($postVar) && strpos($postVar, ';') === false) {

    //This is just my method of obtaining the score/username. I've already checked, that it works fine.
    $score = substr($postVar, strpos($postVar, "score->") + 7);
    $username = substr($postVar, strpos($postVar, "username->") + 10, strpos($postVar, "_") - 10);

    // Perform query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO dbname.tablename (score, username) VALUES(" . $score . ", " . $username . ")";

    if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
    }

    //Close connection
    $con->close();
}
?>
```

NOTE: the code is modelled after the tutorial on [w3schools on an INSERT statement](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp).

Comment: Bad resource, find anything other than w3schools.  You need to learn how to debug.  Error logs are super useful.  Googled this up... http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php

Comment: `$username` is probably a string so it should be in quotes; or preferably use parameterized queries which will handle the quoting.

Comment: Print the $SQL string to the console so that you can see what it *actually* contains.  Also, look at the HTML output of the page in your browser's debugger to see what text-string was included in it, to see if the query worked or not.

Comment: Don't do the `$con->close()` inside the if-block. Shouldn't matter here, but get yourself used to close what you opened. Also you can use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`, it will contain the params sent by POST and GET. I suppose that `$postVar` is empty in your script and that's why it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @ficuscr what's so bad about w3schools, and the specific page he has linked too?

Comment: @Jester, Well it seems to have resulted in poor code that is susceptible to SQL injection.  I opted to blame the teacher and not the student.  A page titled "PHP Insert Data to MySQL' might want to touch on that subject rather than avoid it by using static values.  Yes, w3schools has improved over the last few years, still responsible for promoting a lot of bad habits from prior poor quality content.  I believe there are better resources for learning PHP available these days.

Comment: @ficuscr mmm, that is a valid point. Guess because i know not to do that I've overlooked the fact that someone new to MySQL would easily do that after seeing such a page ;') i'll be a bit more careful with the w3school pages.

Comment: I'll admit to a visceral dislike of W3Schools but I try not to project it too much. :)  Feel like they tried to masquerade as somehow being associated with W3C and feel like they have done some shady stuff in the past to saturate search results.  Main take away is to use many different resources when learning and not rely on any one thing alone.  I think open source code projects on GitHub and PHP reference pages are some of the best ways to learn.

Comment: @Martin Hieden, I see what you mean, by the closing outside of the if statement. However, I tested this code earlier by sending a mail to myself, and the $_POST does indeed work. Perhaps it has to do with the string and quotes, as chris85 mentioned. I'll look into printing to console as well, to see exactly what happens. Thank you everyone.